# wxStaticBitmap has no member named "SetScaleMode()"

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Sorry for this (possibly very dumb) question, but I am quite confused: I try to scale a bitmap in wxWidgets v3.0.2 using `SetScaleMode()` [as described in the documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/classwx_static_bitmap.html#ab8a6f1057e0c15549c1c32bc533bcdb3). I used the include statement, though my compiler (GCC following C++11) says that `'class wxStaticBitmap' has no member named 'SetScaleMode'|` and `'Scale_AspectFit' was not declared in this scope|`.
Maybe I overlooked something, below is my (shortened) code:

```
#include <wx/msgdlg.h>
#include <wx/thread.h>
#include <wx/event.h>
#include <wx/statbmp.h>

//(*InternalHeaders(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame)
#include <wx/bitmap.h>
#include <wx/icon.h>
#include <wx/intl.h>
#include <wx/image.h>
#include <wx/string.h>
//*)


//wxTextFile file;


//helper functions
enum wxbuildinfoformat {
    short_f, long_f };

wxString wxbuildinfo(wxbuildinfoformat format)
{
    wxString wxbuild(wxVERSION_STRING);

    if (format == long_f )
    {
#if defined(__WXMSW__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Windows");
#elif defined(__UNIX__)
        wxbuild << _T("-Linux");
#endif

#if wxUSE_UNICODE
        wxbuild << _T("-Unicode build");
#else
        wxbuild << _T("-ANSI build");
#endif // wxUSE_UNICODE
    }

    return wxbuild;
}



//(*IdInit(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame)
const long WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::ID_STATICBITMAP1 = wxNewId();
const long WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::ID_PANEL1 = wxNewId();


BEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame,wxFrame)
    //(*EventTable(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame)

    //*)
END_EVENT_TABLE()


WindowsDgpsGUIFrame::WindowsDgpsGUIFrame(wxWindow* parent,wxWindowID id)
{
    //(*Initialize(WindowsDgpsGUIFrame)

    wxBoxSizer* pBitmapBoxSizer;
    wxBoxSizer* pPanelBoxSizer;

    Create(parent, wxID_ANY, _("SensoRun"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxDEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wxMAXIMIZE_BOX, _T("wxID_ANY"));
    SetForegroundColour(wxColour(187,0,0));
    SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(128,128,128));
    {
        wxIcon FrameIcon;
        FrameIcon.CopyFromBitmap(wxBitmap(wxImage(_T(".\\resources\\sd.ico"))));
        SetIcon(FrameIcon);
    }
    pPanel = new wxPanel(this, ID_PANEL1, wxPoint(280,352), wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL, _T("ID_PANEL1"));
    pPanelBoxSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    pBitmapBoxSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    StaticDirectionBitmap = new wxStaticBitmap(pPanel, ID_STATICBITMAP1, wxBitmap(wxImage(_T(".\\resources\\kein_pfeil.png"))), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxSIMPLE_BORDER, _T("ID_STATICBITMAP1"));
    pBitmapBoxSizer->Add(StaticDirectionBitmap, 1, wxALL|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);
    pPanelBoxSizer->Add(pBitmapBoxSizer, 1, wxALL|wxEXPAND|wxFIXED_MINSIZE|wxALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL|wxALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5);

    StaticDirectionBitmap->SetScaleMode(Scale_AspectFit);
}
```

(I hope I did not delete something important in this snippet, I wanted to make it easier to read)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can surely see in the doc you link to, `wxStaticBitmap::SetScaleMode()` is there `Since 3.1.0`, while you are using "wxWidgets v3.0.2". So just upgrade to the correct version.

Comment: Uh, I've overlooked this completely. Thanks for that.